# How check is Loader working

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

How check is Loader working? `isStared()` dont help me. After `onLoadFinished()` `isStarted()` return always `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [hasRunningLoaders()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager.html#hasRunningLoaders%28%29)

```
getSupportLoaderManager().hasRunningLoaders()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check `isAbondoned()` and `isReset()`

Loader methods: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html

Article: https://plus.google.com/117981280628062796190/posts/8b9RmQvxudb

[image: Loader States Diagram]